# Retrieve large amount of data from REST API GitHub

Tags: github, bigdata, github-api

How to retrieve large amount of data from REST API GitHub? Nowadays it provided only a small amount of data JSON from GitHub timeline, in many cases limited to only 300 events. I need a bigger volume to work in my Master Research and i need to know how to via the REST API.

Comment: That's correct -- event timelines will give you the last 300 events. If you need more than that, you might consider using data from projects like the [(Unofficial) GitHub Archive](http://www.githubarchive.org/) and [ghtorrent](http://ghtorrent.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github's api (and most IMHO good apis) use pagination to reduce load on themselves and clients. you could write a simple script to go through all the "pages" of results one at a time, then combine your results after the fact locally.

more info here:
http://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/

Comment: I thought I would combine multiple results to get a large volume but  I have to make a huge number of requests to achieve this volume since there is an upper bound for the per_page parameter of the API. Thank's Xero